# Dropdown list of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation, dropdown

I have a custom post type, Doctors, that I need to create a dropdown nav for.  I just want it to populate a select list with all the posts of that CPT and navigate to that post on selection.

I'm doing a couple other dropdowns with wp_dropdown_categories, but I guess there's no built in function for listing a post type?

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to use `get_posts` and roll your own drop down.

Something like this (somewhere in `functions.php`):

```
<?php
function wpse34320_type_dropdown( $post_type )
{
    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'  => $post_type,
            'numberposts' => -1
        )
    );
    if( ! $posts ) return;

    $out = '<select id="wpse34320_select"><option>Select a Doctor</option>';
    foreach( $posts as $p )
    {
        $out .= '<option value="' . get_permalink( $p ) . '">' . esc_html( $p->post_title ) . '</option>';
    }
    $out .= '</select>';
    return $out;
}
```

Then in your template...

```
<?php echo wpse34320_type_dropdown( 'doctors' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll try that out.  I need to finally learn PHP...

Comment: Can't seem to get this working - any suggestions?  I'm not even seeing a dropdown...

Answer (score 0):

This function behaves more like `wp_dropdown_categories`

**function**

```
public function wpse34320_get_dropdown_posts( $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'show_option_none'  => 'Select a post', 'name' => null, 'selected' => '', 'echo' => true ) ){

    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'  => $args['post_type'],
            'numberposts' => -1
        )
    );

    $dropdown = '';

    if( $posts ){

        if( !is_string($args['name']) ){

            $args['name'] = $args['post_type'].'_select';
        }

        $dropdown .= '<select id="'.$args['name'].'" name="'.$args['name'].'">';

            $dropdown .= '<option value="-1">'.$args['show_option_none'].'</option>';

            $args['selected'] = intval($args['selected']);

            foreach( $posts as $p ){

                $selected = '';
                if( $p->ID == $args['selected'] ){

                    $selected = ' selected';
                }

                $dropdown .= '<option value="' . $p->ID . '"'.$selected.'>' . esc_html( $p->post_title ) . '</option>';
            }

        $dropdown .= '</select>';           
    }

    if($args['name'] === false){

        return $dropdown;
    }
    else{

        echo $dropdown;
    }
}
```

**use**

```
   $args=array(

            'show_option_none'  => 'Select a custom post type',
            'post_type'         => $post_type,
            'name'              => $name,
            'selected'          => $selected_id,
            'echo'              => true
   );

    wpse34320_get_dropdown_posts($args);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've added a javascript line to 'Jump' directly to the selection.

Before:

```
$out = '<select id="wpse34320_select"><option>Select a Doctor</option>';
```

After:

```
$out = '<form name="jump1"><select name="jump2" id="wpse34320_select" OnChange="location.href=jump1.jump2.options[selectedIndex].value">><option>Select a doctor</option>';
```

Comment: This is really, really annoying for keyboard users. They cannot reach the second page now.