# How to output the content of a Custom Post Type from a drop down form?

Tags: custom-post-types, dropdown

I have a Custom Post Type called office and I output a list of names of these Offices using a dropdown menu from a thread here on WPSE: [Dropdown list of a custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34320/dropdown-list-of-a-custom-post-type).

What I would like to do next is not sending the visitor to the single-office, but instead show a line of text underneath the selected office that outputs a sentence with some info of this office, let's say the excerpt.

I basically want to get something similar as on this website: 
http://www.healthysanfrancisco.org/visitors/How_To_Apply.aspx

What should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be 1 part processing an array, and 1 part jQuery.

```
<?php
// assume you have a loop already

$html_out = '';
$select  = '<select id="office-chooser">';
$select .= '<option value="">Select an Office</option>';

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    // add each div with excerp. It's ID is unique and correlates to value of select drop down
    $html_out .= '<div class="office-entry" id="office-'.$post->ID.'">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div>';
    $select   .= '<option value="office-'.$post->ID.'">'.get_the_title().'</option>';
endwhile;

// wrap up $select
$select .= '</select>';

echo $select;
echo $html_out;

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#office-chooser').change(function(){
            var $selected_office = $(this).val();
            if($selected_office !== ''){
                $('div.office-entry').hide();
                $('#' + $selected_office).show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if you have questions

### Edit:

Adding this style

```
.office-entry { display:none; }
```

should fix things.

Comment: Thanks @GhostToast, this looks a lot different from what I had before based on the snippet from the other thread.
The jQuery part however doesn't seem to do anything. The excerpts are showing both before I have even selected anything. Would that have to do with the fact that the #office-chooser already has been closed?

Comment: I forgot that by default they'll all be showing. Edited to show a style you might use to overcome that. also edited the "show" statement. i think that will work.

Comment: hmm nothing changes, it looks like the jQuery does not have any effect at all. There is no class switching which I sort of expected. There are no javascript errors in the browser, so that is not it.

Comment: I've not tested this, so you might have to fiddle a bit with the jQuery. I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction at least. I also edited that code a couple times, so make sure you have the latest.

Comment: Don't know an awful lot about jQuery, but I will try to figure it out. You definitely helped me with a big step in the right direction! Thanks so much!

Comment: if I add .show myself to the office-entry class and I add a line of CSS `.office-entry.show { display: block; }` then it is all perfect. The trick will be how to add .show to the office-entry class...

Comment: `hide()` and `show()` should affect visibility by basically making inline styles to say "display:none" or "display:block". if you want to go purely class-based, try doing something like `$selection.addClass('office-hider')`, where `.office-hider { display:none;}` or something. `removeClass()` is the counter part. get it?. If you want to discuss further, come find me in Loop chat. I'm there 8-5, M-F usually. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get it. I added the lot to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pV5xL/) and also there it doesn't work. It's almost 5am here, so I'm off to bed now, tomorrow there is another day. Thanks for the invite, I will look there tomorrow.

Comment: playing in jsfiddle, turns out that when I select "onDomReady" it actually does work... :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: well on jsfiddle that is, in my browsers it still doesn't do anything, so tmrw I need to start figuring out what is different with jsfiddle...